# Display sql table bottom to up

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql

How to display sql table, bottom to top in my aspx page?

Just like facebook wall. Last comment shows on top.

I want c# code for it.

Comment: What exactly do you need - the aspx code, the sql statement?  All of it?!

Comment: How do you do it *now*? SQL? c#?

Comment: Please be specific in your question. The SQL code required in mentioned below. Besides that you need to now Gridview and databinding

Comment: The key point is to use an _ORDER BY_ SQL statement, which column to use - I believe you should consider yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to return the sql query in Descending Order. You can achieve this with a SQL query like...

```
Select * from TableName order by ColumnName Desc
```

For Details have a look into this [ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

use below query

```
select * from table order by column DESC
```